# How to add MySQL query results from a loop in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Essentially, I have an object with string keys and values (ex. {"michigan":"minnesota"}).  I'm trying to loop through all of these key value pairs and make a query from my database, and add the result to a list, which will then be what is returned to the front end.

```
var return_list = []

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
            const state1 = key;
            const state2 = obj[key];

            const sql_select = 'SELECT column1,column2 from database WHERE state = ? OR state=?';
        
            db.query(sql_select,[state1,state2], (err,result) => {
                
                return_list.push(result);
            });
        })
```

This is what I have in simplest terms, and would like to send return_list back to the front end. The problem I'm running into is I can console.log the result within db.query call, but I can't push the result to the list or call it anywhere outside of the query.  I'm fairly new to both front end and back end development, so any possible ideas would definitely be helpful!

Comment: can I get to know the context where this function is run in ? because usually this is a back end function and can have easy response methods to respond back to front ends requesting something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `forEach` returns void. 
So you can't wait for the asynchronous code to run before you return it. 
When we're dealing with an array of promises such as db queries ( like in your case ) or API calls, we should wait for every one of them to be executed. 
That's when we use the [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Try doing it like this:

```
const queryResults = await Promise.all(
   Object.keys(obj).map(async (key) => {
    const state1 = key;
    const state2 = obj[key];

    const sql_select = 'SELECT column1,column2 from database WHERE state = ? OR state=?';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      db.query(sql_select,[state1,state2], (err, result) => {
        if (err) 
          return reject(err)
        else
          return resolve(result)
      })
    )
  })
)
console.log('queryResults', queryResults)
// now you give this queryResults back to your FE
```

Small tips for your fresh start:

- never use var, try always use const or if needed, let.
- try always use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ( `() => {...}` ) instead of regular functions ( `function () {...}` ), It's hard to predict which scope this last one is using

Comment: Await needs to be in an async function.  Can I put this in an async function, and then call it?  Also, thanks for the other tips.  I have been only using const except in the above code where I used var haha

Comment: Yeah, surely you can separate this code in a function ant then call it. With express you could do something like the following: ```router.get('myEndpoint', (req, res) => myFunction().then(myQueryResult => res.status(200).json(myQueryResult))```

Comment: Thanks again, it works!  I put the above code in an async function and returned queryResults.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the database transaction is not instant, so you need to use either promises or async-await.

Using async await would be something like this (untested),

```
async function get_return_list () {
    var return_list = []

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
        const state1 = key;
        const state2 = obj[key];
    
        const sql_select = 'SELECT column1,column2 from database WHERE state = ? OR state=?';
    
         await db.query(sql_select,[state1,state2], (err,result) => {
            
            return_list.push(result);
        });
    })

    return return_list
}
```

see for more detail: https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm currently trying different variations but the above still has return_list as an empty list when called right before returning it.  I think it is the right direction, do you have any more insight?  I also had to change the function to async but it sitll does not work

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are working with `mysql2` from npm. Which provides async method of mysql.
Second, Note that when you query `SELECT`, you don't get the "real" result in first. Suppose you get `result`, then, the "real" results are held in `result[0]`.

```
(async () => {
    const promiseArr = [];

    for (const key of Object.keys(yourOBJ)) {
        const state1 = key;
        const state2 = yourOBJ[key];
        const sql_select = 'SELECT column1,column2 from database WHERE state = ? OR state=?';

        promiseArr.push(db.query(sql_select, [state1, state2]));
    }

    let results;

    try {
        results = await Promise.all(promiseArr);
    } catch (e) {
        throw '...';
    }

    const return_list = results.reduce((finalArray, item) => {
        finalArray = [
            ...finalArray,
            ...item[0],
        ]
    }, []);
})();
```